# Mapping Class Group action on triangulated $S^2\times S^1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mapping-class-groups

We know that Mapping Class Group (MCG) of $S^2\times S^1$ is $Z_2$, generated by twists along the sphere (I am restricting to orientation preserving homeomorphisms). MCG does not act on the fundamental group of $S^2\times S^1$. So my question is, how does MCG act, if at all, on the cell complex triangulating $S^2\times S^1$?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

(This is a long comment rather than a complete answer.)
As Igor Rivin points out, the mapping class group is not ${\mathbb Z}_2$. There is another ${\mathbb Z}_2$ direct summand coming from a homeomorphism that reverses the orientation on both $S^1$ and $S^2$, hence preserves the orientation of $S^1\times S^2$.  This homeomorphism can be taken to have order 2 and it seems likely that $S^1\times S^2$ can be triangulated so that the homeomorphism preserves this triangulation. On the other hand, it seems somewhat unlikely that the twist homeomorphism generating the other ${\mathbb Z}_2$ can be realized by a symmetry of a triangulation. This symmetry would have finite order, and the only reason the twist along $S^2$ has order 2 is that $\pi_1SO(3)$ is ${\mathbb Z}_2$, which depends on a well-known but slightly subtle deformation of a $4\pi$ rotation of space to the identity map, the so-called belt trick.  In one lower dimension a Dehn twist on a nontrivial curve on a torus, for example, has infinite order in the mapping class group, so it cannot be realized by a symmetry of a fixed triangulation of the torus. It would be a little surprising if 3 dimensions was different in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to contradict [Kawauchi](https://books.google.com/books?id=gWbyJn7c5G0C&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=mapping%20class%20group%20S2%20x%20S1&source=bl&ots=auCfv6nxX0&sig=_CE2Uh1cAiAWf3cOpeR5tNswqK4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil3-yulLXOAhWFPBQKHb6yBHgQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=mapping%20class%20group%20S2%20x%20S1&f=false) which also has an extensive discussion.

Comment: thank you for the correction. My question was ill posed on so many levels. :)